# Как обновить данные Listview привязанные к CollectionViewSource при его изменении в коде?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, visual-studio-2015

В ресурсах страницы есть CollectionViewSource, выступающий в качестве источника привязки данных для ListView и datatemplate для вывода элементов в listview.

```
<Page.Resources>        
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="ContactsCVS" IsSourceGrouped="True" />
    <DataTemplate x:Name="ContactListViewTemplate" x:DataType="data:AttractionModel">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--<Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse"
                     Grid.RowSpan="2"
                     Width ="32"
                     Height="32"
                     Margin="6"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     Fill="LightGray"/>-->
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{x:Bind name}" 
                       x:Phase="1"  
                       Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                       Margin="12,6,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Text="{x:Bind note}" 
                        x:Phase="2"
                        Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                        Margin="12,0,0,6"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<!--Список-->
<ListView x:Name="MasterListView" 
              SelectionMode="Extended"
              SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
              ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind ContactsCVS.View}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContactListViewTemplate }"
              ItemClick="OnItemClick"
              Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle >
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:GroupInfoList">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Key}" 
                                   Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
```

В коде устанавливаю источник данных для CollectionViewSource.

```
ContactsCVS.Source = Attractions.GetAttractionsGrouped();
```

Все выводится отлично.
Но если я хочу в коде обновить источник данных для ContactsCVS, как мне заставить MasterListView обновить данные на странице?

Первоначальная задача - выводить результаты поиска вместо коллекции элементов.
Возможно это можно реализовать по-другому?
[image: поиск по списку]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, `Source` в `CollectionViewSource` не является `DependencyProperty`. Поэтому я бы посоветовал подменять всю коллекцию. С другой стороны, вам не нужна привязка, так как вы обновляете контент вручную. Получается вот что:

1. Удаляем `CollectionVuewSource` из ресурсов.
2. В том месте, где раньше было `ContactsCVS.Source = Attractions.GetAttractionsGrouped();`, пишем

   ```
   MasterListView.ItemsSource = new CollectionViewSource()
   {
       IsSourceGrouped = true,
       Source = Attractions.GetAttractionsGrouped()
   }.View;
   ```

Comment: ContactsCVS является источником привязки для MasterListView
`ItemsSource="{x:Bind ContactsCVS.View}"` и datatemplate. Что делать с этим?
Вообще подмена коллекции мне нужна для вывода результатов поиска по коллекции. Может это можно организовать по-другому?

Comment: @DmirijP: Я бы вовсе не обновлял Source. Например, можно привязать Source один раз к `ObservableCollection`, а затем просто обновлять `ObservableCollection` (не замещать, а убирать/добавлять элементы). Это по идее более правильный путь.

Comment: Именно, CollectionViewSource всего лишь удобная для сортировки\группировки\фильтрации обертка, а так - должны работать стандартные реализации коллекциий для WPF.